# msal typescript error Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'void | TokenResponse'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code below generates the following TypeScript error for the `response.accessToken`:

> TS2339: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'void | TokenResponse'.
>   [image]

```js
import * as Msal from '@azure/msal-browser'

export async function getTokenPopup(request: Msal.TokenExchangeParameters) {
  return await auth.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(async () => {
    return await auth.acquireTokenPopup(request).catch((error) => {
      console.log('login with popup failed: ', error)
    })
  })
}

const getGraphDetails = async (
  uri: string,
  scopes: Msal.TokenExchangeParameters,
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  return getTokenPopup(scopes).then((response) => {
      return callGraph(uri, response.accessToken, axiosConfig)
  })
}
```

When checking the [TS definition](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/src/response/TokenResponse.ts) of TokenResponse it clearly states that the property `accessToken` is available on the object:

```js
export type TokenResponse = AuthResponse & {
    uniqueId: string;
    tenantId: string;
    scopes: Array<string>;
    tokenType: string;
    idToken: string;
    idTokenClaims: StringDict;
    accessToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    expiresOn: Date;
    account: Account;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note, why don't you using try/catch with await? It is possible that TypeScript sees a possiblity that your `getTokenPopup` returns void. If both of promises will fail, it return void.

Comment: This code is a copy from the example. I just expected it to work with TS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note regard your `catch`, although you are using `await`. I'd write this code like so:

```
import * as Msal from '@azure/msal-browser'

export async function getTokenPopup(request: Msal.TokenExchangeParameters) {
    try {
        return await auth.acquireTokenSilent(request);
    } catch (error) {
        return await auth.acquireTokenPopup(request);
    }
}

const getGraphDetails = async (
    uri: string,
    scopes: Msal.TokenExchangeParameters,
    axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
    try {
        const response = await getTokenPopup(scopes);
        return callGraph(uri, response.accessToken, axiosConfig);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("You could not get a token");
    }
}
```

Now, why you are getting `void` in `response`. There is a possibility, that function `getTokenPopup` will fail both for `acquireTokenSilent` and `acquireTokenPopup`. So that, the function `getTokenPopup` will throw an error (or return nothing, depends on your implementation).

TypeScript sees that and add a `void` type to indicate that there is a possibility to not get a response back.

Comment: I just tested your code with the `async/away` solution and that fixes the error. I have to start working this way as it reads easier too. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Seems like TypeScript couldn't infer the types properly with `catch`, anyway, glad it helped.